# How to target woocommerce element?

Tags: css

I want to target some woocommerce elements on my website and change color and make some css changes. When using the inspector on my website I find:

```
<div class="woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle">
```

and assume I could write the following as a css code in wordpress

```
.woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle {
    background-color #000000 !important;
}
```

When doing this, nothing happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are styling the toggle coupon form in the checkout form. See image [image: checkout page]

You should be styling the `.woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle .woocommerce-info` not the `.woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle` alone.
To do this try this code.

```
.woocommerce .woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle .woocommerce-info{
   background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you so much! :) Do you also know how to show the coupon code field directly. And hide the click field "click here to enter the code" (which you marked red)?

Comment: @yoencaz Please upvote or mark my answer. It is disappointing that some people here downvoted my answer.

Comment: you can try `$('.woocommerce-form-coupon').show();` to show the coupon form and use like `a.showcoupon{ display:none; }` to hide the the link toggle.

Answer (score 1):

The property and value in CSS should be separated by a colon `:`. Like the following:

```
.woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Added it and still nothing happens? For your information the code responds to other css adjustments like position etcetera. But the only thing I want to do is to change the background color :/

Comment: Maybe because other CSS rules have higher specificity? Try to add something like `body .woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle` to see

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for the whole tree, class by class. it should become a larger property, but would work.

```
body class1 class2 .woocommerce-form-coupon-toggle {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
};
```

Comment: Tried out both of your suggestions. Also other kind of combinations of body class1 etcetera. Still nothing :/